# Looping through Records to get total

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, loops, recordset

I have a webpage that I would like to show the total vacation time taken using visual basic.  All the dates are stored in a SQL database.

I want it to get all records in tblworkhours that are for the employee logged into the computer and have a work code of 2 for vacation, and then I will calculate the total vacation hours off.

I set it up to count all records in the table (works fine).  I then figure out the hours off in that record (works fine).  My Problem - After I’m done getting the info from that record, I want to go to the next record to get it’s hours off, and then the next, and so on, until I have the total hours off for that employee.  I can’t figure out how to get it to go to the next record, and the next, and so on until I reach the end of the records.

Example – My select count statement shows I have 2 records where the employee is whoever is logged in and the workcode is vacation (2).

1st record - begin date 6/13/15 - end date of 6/15/15 - So, I calculate 3 days or 24 hrs

2nd record - begin date 6/20/15 - end date 6/20/15 - 1 day or 8 hrs

My code counts how many records - 2. The Do Until statement works fine - It counts 1 and 2 but it's counting the first record 2x. Instead of getting 32 hrs total (1st record hrs plus 2nd record hrs), I'm getting 48 hrs (1st record hrs 2x).

FYI - I'm not having problems adding hours. My code has to calculate the # of hours because the table just has dates and times. 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is my code - I kept out the parts that are working fine:

```vb
    Dim sqlConnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=WillSQL\ict2;Initial Catalog=TimeSQL;Integrated Security=SSPI")

    Dim commandvct As New SqlCommand
    Dim returnvct As Object

    commandvct.CommandText = "Select count(workhoursid) from tblworkhours where Employee = " & rve & " and workcode = 2" 
'workcode 2 is vacation.  Count works fine.  
    commandvct.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    commandvct.Connection = sqlConnection

    sqlConnection.Open()
    returnvct = commandvct.ExecuteScalar
    sqlConnection.Close()

    Do Until returnvct = 0

        returnvct = returnvct - 1
        ' Deleted code that gets how many hours - this code works fine.

    Loop
```

Comment: http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-SUM.asp

Comment: @Matt You should at least provide some content w.r.t. the link.  Links go dead and then make this comment / answer useless.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html). Never use string concatenation to build a SQL query; always use a parameterized query instead.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I'm not having problems adding hours. My code has to calculate the # of hours because the table just has dates and times. I'm having problems going to the next record. For ex, I have 2 records, 1st has begin date of 6/13/15 and end date of 6/15/15 (3 days or 24 hrs), 2nd has begin date 6/20/15, end date 6/20/15 (1 day or 8 hrs).  My code counts how many records -2. It counts 1 and 2, but it does not go to the next record. It's counting the first record 2x. Instead of getting 32 hrs total (1st record hrs plus 2nd record hrs), I'm getting 48 hrs (1st record hrs 2x).

Comment: @user303348, please use the details from your response and modify your question, so it is more clear to everyone. Then everyone won't have to read all of these comments to get the full concept.

Comment: Richard - are you talking about my select statement?  I will rewrite it - my code does get the total number of records with those specs.  I just need it to loop through these records so I can calculate the total hours. Hours in record 1 + Hours in record 2 + ...  Right now, if there's 2 records, it's just counting the hours in record 1 twice, instead of going to the next record to get those hours.  Am I making sense?  If not, can anyone help me re-word this?

Comment: @user3033348: Yes, it's the `SELECT` statement that's vulnerable. You're concatenating a data value into a SQL command, rather than using a parameter. You *might* get away with it in this instance, if the `rve` variable is an integer, but it's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: Edited original question to hopefully make more sense.  And thanks Richard!

Comment: You need to stopp ever thinking about looping through records. In SQL you should operate on the whole set of records. Looping is a very bad thing and you need to break this habit as it takes many many more times to loop through a recordset and perform actions than to operate on all therecords as a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one record based on the SQL query you have in this code.  There is no second record.

The query is returning **one** record that contains the **count** of all records that meet the criteria.  And you are correctly using the `ExecuteScalar` method to get that value.

It is unclear what you are looping through at the end other than just subtracting one from the returned integer each time.  You certainly aren't looping through any data records.

If you need all the records, then select all the records.

```
SELECT * FROM tblworkhours where Employee = " & rve & " and workcode = 2
```

Then use that to return a datareader and loop through the records there.

It has been mentioned you should be using parameters.  That is true but is probably distracting from your main problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show what you can do with Sql language. In this example, I will summarize vacation hours using SQL only

```sql
create table A (name varchar(100), bdate datetime, edate datetime) 

-- I set dates to string, it will convert to rounded dates.
insert into a values ('AAA', '02/05/2015', '02/05/2015') -- 1 day / 8 hrs
insert into a values ('AAA', '06/05/2015', '06/09/2015') -- 5 days / 40 hrs 
insert into a values ('BBB', '02/05/2014', '02/05/2014') -- 1 day / 8 hrs
insert into a values ('BBB', '06/05/2014', '06/07/2014') -- 3 days / 24 hrs

-- But when taking dates out, you need to cut off hours, minutes, etc - use CAST
select name, SUM(case 
                     when CAST(bdate as date) = CAST(edate as date) Then 8
                     else (datediff(day, CAST(bdate as date), CAST(edate as date)) + 1) * 8 -- +1 to make date inclusive
                 end) as vacaHours
from a
where name = 'AAA' -- comment this and all people will return
group by name
```

Output for `AAA` only

`name    vacaHours
 AAA     48`

Output for all

`name    vacaHours
 AAA     48
 BBB     32`

Now, you can open your DataReader and read the values into program

```vb
' They said, sql injection words... this is what you do - notice alias for count
cmd.CommandText = "Select count(workhoursid) as count from tblworkhours where Employee = @1 and workcode = @2" 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", rve)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", 2)
' some code here
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
' some code here

Using reader As IDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    ' do something with each record
    While reader.Read()

        myvar = Convert.ToInt32(reader("count"))

    End While

End Using
```